# Why does `arch` output `i386`?

Tags: macos, universal-binaries

When I run `$ arch` on my 10.9 2012 MacBook Pro, I get the output

```
i386
```

The manpage for `arch` says that

```
the arch command is 2-way universal, 32-bit only
```

However, `$ file "$(which arch)"` gives

```
/usr/bin/arch: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/arch (for architecture x86_64):        Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/arch (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
```

OTOH, `python2.7` is running as a 64-bit executable:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys; print "%x" % sys.maxint'
7fffffffffffffff
```

Also, the kernel is apparently 64-bit:

```
$ file /mach_kernel 
/mach_kernel: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

`uname` agrees:

```
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

..or does it?

```
$ uname -p
i386
```

Answer (score 17):

Here you go:

**uname -p**      print the machine processor architecture name.

**uname -m**      print the machine hardware name.

The **arch** command with no arguments, displays the machine's architecture type.

Ultimately I suspect this is the answer you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763296/os-x-arch-command-incorrect

For further confusion, run:

```
$arch
i386
$machine  
i486
$uname -m
x86_64
$uname -p
i386
```

Comment: Okay, so `arch` runs as 32- or 64-bit, but only reports whether the architecture is PPC or Intel[-derived], and reports Intel using the `i386` label rather than `intel`.  I guess that's what "2-way universal, 32-bit only" means.